# Find $\lim \limits_{x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(\frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y}\right)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y) = \dfrac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y}$.

Does this function have a limit when $(x,y)\to {\bf0}$?

Comment: Recall that $\sin(t)\sim _0t$.

Comment: @GitGud: So, you mean that this limit exists?

Comment: $f$ is the composition of two continuous functions.

Comment: @gammatester : In my book there is an answer for it. It says, the limit does not exist.While I can not find two different limit for it.

Comment: @gammatester "Almost" continuous ;-)

Comment: Some authors insist that for a function to have a limit at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ it should be defined in a punctured neighborhood of that point. Your function is undefined on the line $y=-x$, so it is not defined in any punctured neighborhood of the origin. There those authors can say that the limit does not exist. Some other authors are more lax, and only consider the function in the intersection of a neighborhood of a point and the domain of definition of the function. This becomes more common the deeper you go. Therefore you need to check the definitions used in your book very carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $g(x,y)=x+y$, and it is pretty clear that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} g(x,y)=0$. Now
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{\sin g(x,y)}{g(x,y)}=S(g(x,y)),
$$
where
$$
S(t)=\frac{\sin t}{t}
$$
for $t \neq 0$. Since $\lim_{t \to 0} S(t)=1$, the theorem about limits of composition of functions gives that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)=1$.

Comment: In my book there is an answer for it. It says, the limit does not exist.While I can not find two different limit for it.

Comment: No matter how I can define your symbols, that limit does exist!

Comment: @niki Unless $f$ is defined at $(0,0)$, unless $f(0,0)\neq 1$ and you failed to give us that information, then the limit exists and it is $1$.

Comment: @GitGud ... and even in that case, the limit exists!

Comment: @Siminore I'm too lazy to type this idea. Please open [this](http://s18.postimg.org/p0wixvayh/limit.jpg) picture. Some authors say the limit does not exist at $a$ because the function is defined there, but it exists at $b$ because it's not defined at $b$.

Comment: Well, the limit should not depend on the value of the functions at that single point, but only on its values around it. Otherwise limit=continuity.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the Taylor series for $\sin(x)$ is $x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\dots$. Based on this,

$$\lim_{x,y\to0}\frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y}=\lim_{x,y\to0}\frac{(x+y)-\frac{(x+y)^3}{3!}+\frac{(x+y)^5}{5!}-\frac{(x+y)^7}{7!}+\dots}{x+y}$$$$=\lim_{x,y\to0}1 -\frac{(x+y)^2}{3!}+\frac{(x+y)^4}{5!}-\frac{(x+y)^6}{7!}+\dots=1$$

Answer (score 0):

If you mean $\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)$ (or $x$ and $y$ exchanged) then yes. The limit is $1$ and can be computed either by the taylor's expansion of $\sin$ or via l'Hopitals rule.

Comment: That's not what $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}$ means.

Comment: I know, the question was indifferent before edit.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I edited the question, but I can't possibly interpret it as this the author of this answer has.